# Why is Objective-C converting JSON values to a hash of ASCII character codes?

Tags: iphone, network-programming, node.js, redis, asyncsocket

We are building an iPhone chat application.

When sending from the browser to the iPhone a JSON chat message:

```
    {"content":"Hi"}
```

The iPhone receives:

```
    {"content":{"0":72,"1":105,"length":2}}
```

But, we intend for it to receive the same exact message.

To reproduce this issue, first install node.js & redis. Then:

- Get the code:

  ```
  git clone git://github.com/acani/acani.git
  cd acani
  git submodule update --init
  ```
- Start Redis on the default port.
- From http://github.com/acani/acani-node:

  ```
  node acani-node-server.js # run node.js chat server
  # open index.html in a Google Chrome or Firefox and follow instructions.
  ```
- Open Lovers.xcodeproj located in http://github.com/acani/acani-chat/tree/master/Lovers2/, and change LoversAppDelegate.m to initially load the ChatViewController instead of the HomeViewController.

  ```
  homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] init]; # comment out this line
  # change the next line to:
  navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[ChatViewController alloc] init]];
  # Then, build & run.
  ```

Comment: Can you show the relevant Objective-C code where you actually parse the JSON? What JSON framework are you using?

Comment: It's not the converting of the JSON string into an NSDictionary; that works. I know because I put an NSLog after this line: http://github.com/acani/acani-chat/blob/master/Lovers2/ZTWebSocket.m#L207 and it shows that the characters of the value of the JSON string have been translated to ASCII codes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We figured it out. It wasn't the iPhone or Objective-C at all. The conversion error was happening on the node.js server. We forgot to put quotes around the string values of the JSON object, and so the `JSON.stringify()` JavaScript function was converting the strings as shown above... except we were doing something like: `{"content":Hi}`. When we changed it to: `{"content":"Hi"}`, it worked fine. Duhh...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you need to escape the string (JSON) being sent, using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding and then unescape it on receipt.

The first three numbers are 072 - in decimal that's 'H'. Which makes me think a " might be getting lost due to transmission without encoding. There are other things against this theory but I think it is worth looking at.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. I'll try that tonight and report back. I guess I figured the AsyncSocket library would take care of that...